# Did Disney address whether they will release "Making of" book of Episode VII?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Episode VI had a very interesting "The Making of Star Wars: Return of the Jedi" book, detailing all sorts of curious details, from older scripts, to production details and quotes, to on-location photos and discussions.

**Is there any indication from Lucasfilm or Disney on whether they will publish something similar for The Force Awakens?** *(and "The Art of..." that was released does not seem to be at all similar to me)*

Comment: I will be OK with answers based on OTHER Disney properties if there seems to be a pattern that TFA would fit in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes

*The Making of Star Wars: The Force Awakens* will be released in hardcover in North America in October 2016.  It comes with a foreward by director J.J. Abrams and producer Kathleen Kennedy.

You can pre-order it [here](http://www.amazon.ca/The-Making-Star-Wars-Awakens/dp/1419720228)!